# How to combine a flat arrays into hierarchy in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hierarchical-data

say I have a data structure like this:

```
const flat = [
 [
  {
    id: 0,
    schema: "class",
    name: "basement below baseLevel"
  }
  {
    id: 1,
    schema: "class",
    name: "baseLevel"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    schema: "TopLevelClass",
    name: "The Top"
  },
 ],
 [
  {
    id: 3,
    schema: "class",
    name: "Second base level"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    schema: "TopLevelClass",
    name: "The Top"
  }
 ]
]
```

The structure assumes a nested hierarchy where the root is the last element of each inner array. I need to restructure the data to look like this:

```
const root = [
  id: 2,
  schema: "TopLevelClass",
  name: "The Top",
  children: [
    {
      id: 1,
      schema: "class",
      name: "base Level",
      children: [
        {
         id: 0,
         schema: "class",
         name: "Basement below base level"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      schema: "class",
      name: "Second base level"
    }
  ]
]
```

There are some examples that combine arrays into hierarchies similar to this, but they always include either a parent or child id and the data structure I am working with does not. It just assumes (I know this is probably not a good assumption to be making, but its what I am working with) that each inner array is structured base up. Is there a concise way to nest the flattened array into a hierarchy?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: Did you still facing this problem?